# can't save joomla content because i have too many usergroups

Tags: joomla

When you have lots of user groups joomla fails to save your content. It is something to do with the way joomla validates forms

Is there anyone that has resolved this issue in Joomla 2.5.* or 3.*?

Is there a modified mootools-more.js or more-tools-core.js and validate.js that fixes this?

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this with a partial answer.

I went to the assets table in the database and changed the rule field to long text and then i set max_input_vars = 5000 in my php.ini and now it is saving articles again.

I didn't need to modify any js files to do this.